# list of procedures called in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Is there an easy way to extract/document the list of the procedures/functions that are called when a VBA project is run? Just to clarify, the VBA project handles several algorithms, and each algorithm uses/calls only a specific set of procedures/functions within the VBA project.

NOTE: One way I achieved this was to use the extensibility library to programmatically add a single line to each procedure/function that would append the name of the respective procedure/function to a text file. But after doing that my Excel installation started complaining about my VBA project (Add-in). So I am looking for alternative ways.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for debugging? It's not clear to me what you would gain from this that can't be learned by just looking at the code itself.

Comment: In what way was it "complaining"?

Comment: @DGH, I am using this for a combination of understanding/debugging/documenting the code. I started a new position and as part of that I am working on this humongous (~80,000 lines) VBA project. I can for sure run the project line-by-line, but that gets frustrating.

Comment: @TimWilliams, when loading the Add-in upon running excel for the first time. It wouldn't allow me to debug at that point to figure out what was going wrong (would show me the error message with the debug button inactive). My guess is there were some issues with loading the global variables.

Comment: Pressing CTRL+L while debugging the will give you the current call stack, but I don't know a way to export it... :)

Comment: @OlleSjögren, I'd like to preferrably automate the whole process if possible.

Comment: There are a few tools available for VBA code anlysis.  You could maybe start with MZ Tools (free) and see if that can tell you anything...

Comment: @TimWilliams, MZ Tools sounds neat, I have to find a 32-bit machine though. I'll definitely look into it. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Good luck!  In then end though you still have to read all the code ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Put a code in each procedures/functions that will store some values in a sheet or somewhere else.